# Creating db connection string with credentials stored in AWS secrets manager

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to use EF Core in ASP.NET Core with db credentials stored in AWS Secrets Manager.

I want to register dbContext like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer("connection_string"));
```

In order to do that I need data (username, password, host) from SecretsManager. The only problem is that all actions on AmazonSecretsManagerClient are async and `ConfigureServices` in Startup is synchronous.

Building dependency injection tree should be kept simple, so this feels like downloading configuration and I think it should be performed before building dependency tree.

It feels like it should be a common problem, but I'm unable to find reliable solution. How should I approach this?

Comment: Have read blow blogs, it should be the best practise when using `Aws secrets`. [Blogs1](https://andrewlock.net/secure-secrets-storage-for-asp-net-core-with-aws-secrets-manager-part-1/) and [Blogs2](https://andrewlock.net/secure-secrets-storage-for-asp-net-core-with-aws-secrets-manager-part-2/)